# Unable to install INET4.3.5 with OMNET++ Pre15 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, omnet++, inet

According to the OMNET installation guide, I am able to run Aloha example with OMNET++

According to [INET Install guide](https://inet.omnetpp.org/Installation.html). I went to Help -> Install Simulation Models and tried to install INET 4.3.5. But it failed.

Build console output:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) select
>>> referenced by inet/common/scheduler/RealTimeScheduler.cc:135
>>> referenced 42 more times

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) ntohs
>>> referenced 88 more times
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
D:\OMNET\omnetpp-6.0pre15\tools\win32.x86_64\mingw64\bin/llvm-ar.exe: error: unable to load '../out/clang-debug/src/libINET_dbg.dll.a': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1762: ../out/clang-debug/src/libINET_dbg.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/OMNET/omnetpp-6.0pre15/samples/inet4.3/src'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Kindly help in installing inet framework on Windows10.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, on Windows, INET has t o be updated to compile properly. Until a new INET release is coming out, you can do this change, to make it compile:

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/commit/676711aa40a7cfd495f2afb9136a0562cf8cb871

Comment: After changing src/makefrag file, omnet++ can make it compile. But it is unable to run  examples of Inet(inet/examples/ethernet/preemption). Meanwhile console outputs nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know if it is possible to install older versions of inet in omnet++Pre15. I want to build flora environment that requires OMNET++6 and INET4.3.*.

Comment: I have released INET 4.3.6 that contains the above fix.